# Is $S_3$ an exceptional Lie group?

Tags: lie-groups

Up until now I have had the belief that finite groups do not supply meaningful examples of Lie groups. However in [this paper](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-94-015-7809-7_4), Kostant claims that the symmetric group on three elements is an exceptional Lie group (page 66). What is the meaning of this?

Comment: Well, finite group with the discrete topology *is* a zero dimensional manifold....

Comment: Yes, this is my point: the Lie group structure doesn't seem to say much, and in particular the Lie algebra vanishes.

Comment: To be a little less tongue-in-cheek, I have heard people talk about q-analogues in a way that suggests that the symmetric groups are somehow a degeneration of $GL_n$, and that to the extent that we have a theory of the "field with one element", $GL_n(\mathbb F_1)=S_n$, or something along those lines.  I don't know how much of this is a just a collection of analogies and how much can be made rigorous, and I certainly don't know if it is what Kostant was thinking of, but it is at least part of a mathematical fairly tale that I've heard about (though have never really heard directly or in full).